# how to stay logged in after killing an app using email authentication in swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There seems to be no code related to Firebase authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Autologin in Firebase, you can stay logged in even if you closed the app.

I call the following code in my `LoginViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    AuthService.automaticSignIn {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToErrorVC", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Here the content of `AuthService.automaticSignIn`:

```
static func automaticSignIn(onSuccess: @escaping () -> Void){
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                onSuccess()
            })
        }
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```